# Creating a new object based on confirm() result

Tags: javascript, html

Can someone help me understand why this doesn't work. Here is my JS code:

```
function Agent(codename, str, acc, spd, int, lock, cqc, stl, lck) {
    "use strict";
    this.codename = codename;
    this.str = str;
    this.acc = acc;
    this.spd = spd;
    this.int = int;
    this.lock = lock;
    this.cqc = cqc;
    this.stl = stl;
    this.lck = lck;
    this.avg = function () {
        return (this.str + this.acc + this.spd + this.int + this.lock + this.cqc + this.stl + this.lck) / 8;
    };
}

document.getElementById("ace-select").addEventListener("click", function () {
    "use strict";
    var r = confirm("Are you sure you want Ace?");
    if (r === true) {
        var ace = new Agent("Ace", 8, 9, 9, 9, 8, 10, 10, 5);
    }
}, false);
```

Here is my HTML for the button:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-border select-color" id="ace-select" type='submit' role="button">Select</button>
```

When I test this in Chrome, clicking the button brings up the confirm() prompt as expected but clicking OK does not create my object as expected. i get the error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: ace is not defined at :1:1"

If I take this exact same code and put it right into the console however, it works just fine. In this case, I paste the object constructor in as-is but I leave out the EventListener part and only paste in:

```
var r = confirm("Are you sure you want Ace?");
        if (r === true) {
            var ace = new Agent("Ace", 8, 9, 9, 9, 8, 10, 10, 5);
        }
```

As before, the confirm() box pops up and when I click OK, it evaluates to `true` as expected and my object is created.

What am I doing wrong that it won't work when I have it inside the event listener?

Comment: If I should be doing this an entirely different way, please feel free to advise. The purpose of me doing any of this is to get experience in writing code and I fully expect to find problems, like this, that I need to solve and I'm well aware that learning best practices will be a part of this.

Comment: i think the error is not in the declaration. do you call ace for a output anythere? the scope on ace is only in the if and nowhere else.

Comment: The scope of `ace` is the `function` it's in, **not** the if statement. You can test this by adding `console.log(ace)` after the if statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the variable scope. Since `ace` is being declared as a variable inside of an anonymous function, it is only accessible to that function.

That's why you get an error when you try to access it via the console (or anywhere else, such as another function outside of that function).

This is just how JavaScript works, there's more information about scope here: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

If you want to use `ace` outside of its local scope then there's a couple of ways you can go about it if you use a different design pattern. For example a revealing module: https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#revealingmodulepatternjavascript (this book has lots of wonderful and free information on JavaScript design patterns, I highly recommend reading through it).

Another way is to simply experiment with creating custom objects:

```
AGX = {};
AGX.Learning = {
    createAgent: function(options) {
        console.log(AGX.Learning.agent);
        console.log((options.str + options.acc + options.spd + options.int + options.lock + options.cqc + options.stl + options.lck) / 8);
    }
}

var createAgentOptions = {
    str: 2,
    acc: 5,
    spd: 7,
    int: 2,
    lock: 30,
    cqc: 4,
    stl: 3,
    lck: 29
};
AGX.Learning.agent = 'Ace';
AGX.Learning.createAgent(createAgentOptions);
```

In the above example, `Learning`is an object being added to your parent object `AGX`. From there `agent` is being stored in the `Learning` object too, which is then used by the `createAgent()` function.

I would recommend playing around with this as although it's basic it'll help you to learn the JS fundamentals (nearly everything in JS is an object) and then going through the different design patterns in the linked book.

Comment: You know what, I didn't even think about the scope. You're absolutely right. I'll keep that in the mind in the future. Many thanks!

Comment: Happy to help :).